# Blazor server side checkboxlist component does not update the model

Tags: blazor, checkboxlist

Trying to develop a generic CheckBoxList Blazor server side component for .NET6 but I can't get the model updated on submitting the form.
The component property getter is never called despite editContext is set to Modified.
Here is the component:

```
@typeparam TItem

@if(AllValues != null)
{
    foreach(ListItem item in ListItems)
    {
        <div class="Item">
            <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="@item.IsChecked" />
            @item.Text
        </div>
    }
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public List<TItem> AllValues { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public Func<TItem, string> TextField { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Func<TItem, object> ValueField { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<List<TItem>> CheckedValuesChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public List<TItem> CheckedValues
    {
        get
        {
            var retval = AllValues.Where(x => IsChecked(x)).ToList();
            return retval;
        }
        set
        {
            var listItemsToCheck = Convert(value);
            ListItems = Convert(AllValues);
            foreach(var listItem in ListItems)
            {
                listItem.IsChecked = listItemsToCheck.Any(x => x.Value == listItem.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsChecked(TItem item)
    {
        var itemValue = ValueField?.Invoke(item).ToString() ?? "";
        ListItem? listItem = ListItems.FirstOrDefault(x => itemValue == x.Value );
        return listItem?.IsChecked ?? false;
    }

    private List<ListItem> ListItems = new();

    private List<ListItem> Convert(List<TItem> items)
    {
        var retval = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach(var item in items) {
            var listItem = Convert(item);
            retval.Add(listItem);
        }
        return retval;
    }

    private ListItem Convert(TItem item) => new ListItem
        {
            Value = ValueField?.Invoke(item).ToString() ?? "",
            Text = TextField?.Invoke(item) ?? "?"
        };

    private TItem? Convert(ListItem listItem) => AllValues.
    FirstOrDefault(x => ValueField?.Invoke(x).ToString() == listItem.Value);

    private List<TItem> Convert(List<ListItem> listItems) => AllValues.
    Where(x => listItems.Any(y => ValueField?.Invoke(x).ToString() == y.Value)).ToList();

    protected class ListItem
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here a sample page to test it with a season enum:

```
@page "/TestCheckBoxList"
@layout EmptyLayout;

<EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit=@ValidFormSubmitted>
    <CheckBoxList AllValues="@AllSeasons"
                  TextField="@((item)=>item.ToString())"
                  ValueField="@((item)=>((int)item).ToString())"
                  @bind-CheckedValues="@Model.Seasons">
    </CheckBoxList>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
</EditForm>

<div>Checked seasons:</div>
@foreach (var season in CheckedSeasons)
{
    <div>@season.ToString()</div>
}

@code {
    private List<Seasons> AllSeasons = Enum.GetValues<Seasons>().ToList();
    private List<Seasons> CheckedSeasons = new();
    private TestClass Model = new();


    private enum Seasons : int
    {
        Winter,
        Spring,
        Summer,
        Autumn
    }

    protected async Task ValidFormSubmitted(EditContext editContext)
    {
        if (editContext.IsModified())
        {
            CheckedSeasons = Model.Seasons;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    private class TestClass
    {
        public List<Seasons> Seasons = new();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finaly realized that my best option was to forget about inputcheckbox control on my component and use a standard html input checkbox.

It successfully updates the model but it does not update EditContext.IsModified() flag so I had to skip this and validate the model no matter if the user edited it.

Inheriting the component from InputBase and using inputcheckbox control successfully updates EditContext.IsModified() flag but it does not update the model.

This is my component final version in case it helps somebody:

```
@typeparam TItem

@if (AllValues != null)
{
    foreach (TItem item in AllValues)
    {
        var Text = TextField?.Invoke(item);
        var Value = ValueField?.Invoke(item).ToString();
        bool Checked = SelectedValues.Contains(item);

        <div class="Item">
            <input type="checkbox" checked=@Checked
            @onchange="eventArgs => { CheckboxClicked(item, eventArgs.Value); }" />
            @Text
        </div>
    }
}

@code {

    [Parameter] public List<TItem> AllValues { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public Func<TItem, string>? TextField { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Func<TItem, object>? ValueField { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public List<TItem> SelectedValues { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<List<TItem>> SelectedValuesChanged { get; set; }

    public async Task CheckboxClicked(TItem item, object isChecked)
    {
        if ((bool)isChecked)
            if (!SelectedValues.Contains(item)) SelectedValues.Add(item);
        else
            if (SelectedValues.Contains(item)) SelectedValues.Remove(item);
    }

}
```

and this is the final page to test it:

```
@page "/"

<EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit=@ValidFormSubmitted>

    <CheckBoxList AllValues="@AllSeasons"
                  TextField="@((item)=>item.ToString())"
                  ValueField="@((item)=>((int)item).ToString())"
                  @bind-SelectedValues="@Model.Seasons">
    </CheckBoxList>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>

</EditForm>

<div>Checked seasons:</div>

@foreach (var season in CheckedSeasons)
{
    <div>@season.ToString()</div>
}

@code {
    private List<Seasons> AllSeasons = Enum.GetValues<Seasons>().ToList();
    private TestClass Model = new();
    private List<Seasons> CheckedSeasons = new();

    public enum Seasons : int
    {
        Winter,
        Spring,
        Summer,
        Autumn
    }

    protected async Task ValidFormSubmitted(EditContext editContext)
    {
        CheckedSeasons = Model.Seasons;
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public List<Seasons> Seasons = new();
    }
}
```